Using a pre-rendered image of a plot within a Mathematica Figure
I want to plot new data over data that I only have in the form of a figure in order to be able to make a comparison.
Say for example I have only the image (not the original data) produced by (or better yet assume it as been produced by other software, e.g. a screenshot, so that there is no Mathematica meta data available).
Export["exampleImage.png", Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}]

And I want to combine this with say
Plot[2Cos[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Red]

Is there any easy way to rescale the "image" (preferably not actually changing the number of pixels). So that I can easily combine these. (Note I would like to for example extend this data I plot over the image beyond the axes of the original image. (It is not that important that the axes are extended though if it can be done without it looking weird this might be nice to add.)
(Assume the image comes with a clear axes but that the scale and plot range can differ from the new plot we want to plot over the image.)

As the axes in the given picture are unchangeable, you must scale the new plot to suit the given axes. Eg.
Export[name = "d:/tmp/exampleImage.png", Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2   Pi}]];
pic = Import[name]


Now we must make the second plot according to these axes by choosing the x range and the PlotRange accordingly. In this case we need 0<=x<=10 and -1.1<=y<=1.1. Then we need to transform the plot to an image using "Image". And we need also the option "Background->None" in the plot. Otherwise the plot is opaque for the picture:
gr = Plot[2 Cos[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> 1.1 {-1, 1}, Background -> None]
ImageCompose[pic, Image[gr]


.

thanks. I guess I should have given a slightly more complicated and clearer example. This does seem to work remarkably easy with basically no work done you can combine the images as if the axes data of the image is already known. I suspect this methods works because the picture still has some Mathematica metadata? I'd like a method that works for an image that has no such data. The problem I want to solve is exactly how to provide "coordinates" to an image.

How about editing your question with more realistic example data attached? Then you can expect more reaction.
